# sensor for human detection

Tags: tablet

I have a customer that would like to have a display that detects when a human walks up to a screen (distance like from a standard terminal) that sensor then needs to trigger a display of some data.

existing conditions:

- wifi is present
- high metal environment (construction hall)
- medium to cheap price range

What kind of sensors should I look at?

Comment: There are floor mats that can detect when somebody stands on them. These mats use [velostat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velostat) which changes resistance under pressure.

Comment: You might also try passive infrared sensors (PIR), which are less reliable than a mat, but require no contact and are not raised above floor level, e.g., https://www.amazon.com/Onyehn-Pyroelectric-Infrared-Detector-Modules/dp/B07GJDJV63/ref=sr_1_8

Comment: How accurate can it be? Do you allow false positives?  What's your budget?

Comment: false positives are allowed but should not have alot of it. Budget is under discussion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start with a [pressure sensitive floor mat](https://www.ebay.com/i/283807213427?chn=ps&norover=1&mkevt=1&mkrid=711-117182-37290-0&mkcid=2&itemid=283807213427&targetid=883564623986&device=c&mktype=pla&googleloc=9032873&poi=&campaignid=6469750549&mkgroupid=93041470030&rlsatarget=pla-883564623986&abcId=1141176&merchantid=119303975) which gives a switch closure when someone steps on the mat, or an infrared sensor which [senses a person](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/arduino-with-pir-motion-sensor/) [by reflection from an infrared LED](https://store.arduino.cc/usa/grove-infrared-reflective-sensor-v1-2). The latter does work on folks wearing black, BTW.  Either would be monitored by an [Arduino controller](https://www.arduino.cc/) which, when presence is selected, provides power to the monitor [through a relay](https://www.adafruit.com/product/3191).